# Erasing Hive Registry

Tags: kernel, registry, driver, windows-ce

I have been trying to erase the Hive registry.

Luckily, I found this forum(http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/04/28/windows-ce-cleaning-the-registry-hive.aspx) which tells me that it can be done by adding a new functionality in the kernelIoControl. I tried to call it and debugged it within one of the drivers and found that when I called  kernelIoControl, It lead me to XXX_KernelIoControl function in  C:\WINCE800\private\winceos\coreos\core\thunks\tkfuncs.cpp. At the end of the function, KernelIoControl is being called and I don't have access to the source code anymore (took me to assembly code).

The forum provided an example code for setting the flag to erase the hive registry (see code below).

```
DWORD *pFlags = (DWORD *)lpInBuf;
BOOL *pClean = (BOOL *)lpOutBuf;

*pfClean = FALSE;

if((*pdwFlags == HIVECLEANFLAG_SYSTEM) || (*pdwFlags == HIVECLEANFLAG_USERS))
{
                if(CheckSharedMemoryHiveDeleteFlag())
                {
                                *pClean = TRUE;
                }
}
return TRUE;
```

What I don't understand is I could not find *pclean anywhere(assuming the variable name is correct). Also, Microsoft provides the same information (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/ms904450?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which still uses *pclean. So in a nut shell, I have been finding a way to set the flag to erase the hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pClean is the output parameter of the IoControl call, it's obtained by casting the pointer to a BOOL in the 2nd row of your code.
By setting it to TRUE (and returning TRUE from your IoControl routine) you'll tell the system to discard contents of the hive files.

Comment: So wince already has some additional function call that detects IOCTL_HAL_GET_HIVE_CLEAN_FLAG ?

Comment: the OS calls a generic function in your OAL named OEMIoControl, here you may have a case statement or (most commonly) a table that calls a function for each different IOCTL_* code that is supported by the OAL.

Comment: You should find that implementation to understand if the specific IOCTL is already handled somewhere in you BSP

Comment: Yes, you are right . I leaned that IOCTL_HAL_GET_HIVE_CLEAN_FLAG automatically gets called. I also finally understood that setting lpOutBuf to true triggers the underlying function calls to set the flag necessary to erase the hive.

Comment: Yes, there are many IOCTLs that are called by various OS components, implementing a handler for them allows you to customize the os behaviour without having to change any os component. Unfortunately, many of them are well buried inside the documentation :(